# No entiendo que hay de mal en esta condicional

Tags: c++

Este programa sirve para contar los multiplos de 2 desde un punto de inicio,los pone en una array y las imprime en pantalla

Tengo una pregunta, estoy practicando c++ y bueno estoy haciendo un ejercicio pero veo que esta condicional la pasa pero es falsa

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    //Probando condicionales y bucles
    //Declaracion de variables
    int a[10];
    int b = 0;
    int i = 0;
    bool centinela = true;
    //Personalizacion y interface
    system("color 4f");
    cout << "Ingrese un numero" << endl;
    cin >> b;
```

a es una array para guardar los multiplos, b es el punto de inicio y i es un iterador, el centinela lo queria usar para otra cosa pero sirve para ver si se lleno la array y va abajo

```
//Logica (Bucle, condicionales)
for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(a); i++) {
    if (b % 2 != 0) {
        cout << "El numero ingresado no es multiplo de dos" << endl;
        centinela = false;
        system("pause");
        break;
    } else {
        a[i] = b;
        b++;
        centinela = true;


    }
}
```

Aca imprimo los numero si la condicion es verdadera

```
if (centinela == true) {
    cout << "Los numeros multiplo de dos son: "<<endl;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;

    }

}
```

Ahi esta mi codigo completo, con esto puedo deberia imprimir todos los numeros en la array

Comment: ¿Cómo declaras e inicializas b?

Comment: Ya esta completo el codigo

Comment: Cuando ingresas un número par, por ejemplo, 2, pasa lo siguiente:
La condición es falsa, guardas el número. Sumas 1 a b, que ahora es igual a 3.
Vuelves arriba en el bucle, y ahora la condición es verdadera (3 % 2 != 0), por ende imprimes la línea y sales del bucle.
pd: en C++, `sizeof` te devuelve el tamaño en bytes, no el largo de un array.

Comment: @CamiloGomez considera escribir una respuesta en vez de un comentario

Comment: aunque parezca obvio, podrías editar la pregunta y explicar cual es el propósito del código y lo que pretendes lograr.

Comment: Ya esta, soy nuevo en Stackoverflow y en programar en si.

Answer (score 0):

El `sizeof` del primer bucle te devuelve el valor mínimo de 40 (los bytes que ocupa `a`), y no 10, que supongo es lo que esperas (ya que el arreglo es de 10 elementos).

Cambiando a :

```
for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
    if (b % 2 != 0) {
        cout << "El numero ingresado no es multiplo de dos" << endl;
        centinela = false;
        return 1;
        break;
    } else {
        a[i] = b;
        b++;
        centinela = true;
    }
}
```

Con esto ya logras obtener el 10 sin embargo, como te indican en otro comentario, al introducir un numero par en la siguiente iteración será impar y pondra `centinela = false` , esto hace que nunca entre en el `if` de abajo, ademas el `system(pause)` no te dejara continuar.

Ademas los bucles for utilizas `<=` , esto incluye la ultima iteracion, por lo tanto estaras haciendo 11 iteraciones. debes utilizar `i<TAMAÑO` o `i<=TAMAÑO-1`.

Te adjunto la modificacion para que te funcione como creo que quieres.

```
#include <iostream>
                
using namespace std;
int main() {
    //Probando condicionales y bucles
    //Declaracion de variables
    int a[10]={0};
    int b = 0;
    int i = 0;
    bool centinela = true;

    //Personalizacion y interface
    cout << "Ingrese un numero" << endl;
    cin >> b;
         
    //Logica (Bucle, condicionales)
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
        if ((b % 2 != 0)){
            cout << "El numero ingresado no es multiplo de dos" << endl;
            centinela = false;
            break;
        } else {
            a[i] = b;
            b++;
            centinela = true;
        }
    }
    cout << "Los numeros multiplo de dos son: "<<endl;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 porque: Seguís seteando `centinela` que no tiene ningún sentido. `i` debería declararse en los scopes propios de cada bucle `for (int i=0; ...)`,  usás `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])` en el primer bucle, pero usás `10` hardcodeado en el segundo. El valor de `sizeof(a)` no devuelve necesariamente 40 porque el estándar de C++ **no define un tamaño fijo para los tipos**. `system(pause)` no supone un problema.

Comment: Evidentemente no hace falta el sizeof, se puede poner 10 y ya, el seguramente estaba queriendo practicar el dejar fijo la condición y cambiar el tamaño del arreglo posiblemente, sino no tiene sentido en uno hardcode y en otro no
Es totalmente falso tener que definir el 'int i' en el for, eso será tu gusto, pero no es ni óptimo ni obligatorio.
Un system pause supone una pausa para el programa si está ejecutandolo en Windows, deberías chequear mejor antes de comentar sin sentido

Comment: Se puede poner el 10, se debería usar una constante o una constexpr igual en ambos loops. `for (int i=0;...)` no es obligatorio, es óptimo. Permite advertir usos erróneos y, junto con `-Wshadow`, encontrar usos anidados de `i` (*Se supone que el compilador puede hacer optimizaciones adicionales. Dudo que afecte en loops razonablemente chicos*). `system ("pause")` es un hack común en Win para evitar que la consola se cierre. Sólo hay que presionar una tecla. Por favor, usa @D4RIO para que SO me notifique del comentario, y no incluyas sarcasmos o agresión, que no aportan.